# Visual Studio 2017 Kinect for Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10-universal

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2014/10/31/kinect-with-me-part-2-tracking-bodies-and-overlaying-shapes-on-infrared-data/) using Visual Studio Community 2017. However, whenever I try to compile, I get this error:

> framework identity 'Name = Microsoft.WindowsPreview.Kinect.8.1,
>   MinVersion = 2.0.1410.19000'. It is expected to have three parts
>   delimited by a comma.

I believe the issue has to do with the loss of support for windows 8.1 in Visual Studio 2017, since I did create a blank universal windows app, and had to make the target OS Windows 10.

I can't just create a WPF file, because then I can't follow the tutorial anymore, but the only other solution I saw (to make use a windows 8.1 project template) doesn't work because Visual Studio no longer supports 8.1

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also using windows 10 and have been able to complete and followed [This Tutorial](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring15/group02/assets/docs/dzappnote.pdf) to get infrared working on WPF with kinect. Do give it a try as it worked for me. I have it working on my github [Here](https://github.com/bingcheng45/KinectStreamWithCamera)

Cheers!